# WebView removing spaces from text

Tags: android, html, webview

I'm using a WebView to display a formatted HTML text file with color and font size.

My problem is it keeps removing spaces form the text, like it will combine two words together. I think it is because it is trying to fit the text within the screen width. How do I fix this? Or is there a better way to display formatted text like this? (I need size, color, links, and some centered text

Also, how do I remove the white background underneath the scrollbar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does the text file have HTML character for a space `"&nbsp;"`?  If not, that might help.

Comment: It does, should I remove that? Sorry, I'm not really an HTML guy :)

Comment: Removing those tags didn't change anything, but I think I found the problem. I'll post it here.