# Android WebView removing spaces from text

Tags: android, webview

I'm using a WebView to display a formatted HTML text file with color and font size.

My problem is it keeps removing spaces form the text, like it will combine two words together. I think it is because it is trying to fit the text within the screen width. How do I fix this? Or is there a better way to display formatted text like this? (I need size, color, links, and some centered text

This question has been already asked but was not answered.
[WebView removing spaces from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669265/webview-removing-spaces-from-text)

Comment: can you post your html text and how do you try to show it in webview code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need load formatted local html file, so algorithm:

- Parse you unformatted html data.
- Format html data as you like, using .replace method
- Load formatted data to your webview, like this: [Load local html in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543349/load-local-html-in-webview)

Comment: This solution load HTML from a String variable. Worked for me

String html = "<html><body>Hello, World!</body></html>";
String mime = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";

WebView myWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);